# Load a kml received from a script onto google maps, getting "INVALID REQUEST"

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm trying to add a kml file received from a php script to load onto google maps using the kmlLayer object from Google Maps Api. I'm receiveing a `"INVALID REQUEST"` error from the kmlLayer constructor.

```
function renderKML(fileUrl) {
    var kml = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          url: fileUrl,             
          map: map         
    });         

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(kml, 'status_changed', function () {             
        console.log('KML status is', kml.getStatus());           
    });     
}
```

I've validated this function with the kml url used in the maps api, which properly renders the kml layer.

When I try to run with a kml loaded with this php script however

```
$id = $_GET['id']; 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM kml WHERE id = $id"; 
$results = $DBQueries->statement($link, $sql); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results); 

header("Content-type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='layer.kml'"); 

echo $row['kml'];
```

I receive a:

> "INVALID REQUEST" error.

I've tried a dozen combinations of header types, I even tried to mask the url as an .kml with a .htaccess file without luck.

The KML I'm testing with is valid, I've loaded it manually into maps with other software and wouldn't I receive

> `"INVALID DOCUMENT"`

if that was the case?

I've seen multiple similar questions but all having:

> "INVALID DOCUMENT"

as error code and syntactic error. Not the compatibility between maps api and script URLs.

Is there something missing or is this just a bad aproach?

Comment: Does your KML meet the [restrictions on KML in the Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#restrictions)? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kiqccezzbktn52f/layer.kml?dl=0) This is the kml file, also this kml, strapt to the bare minimum does give the same error [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1dn9c01bk27q1uc/cornishlight.kml?dl=0)

Comment: [Your KML is invalid (hence the "INVALID DOCUMENT" error)](http://www.feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fkml%2FSO_20170326_layer.kml). [Fixed KML displayed on KmlLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20170326_layer_fixed.kml)

Comment: Did you ever figure out why you're getting the INVALID_REQUEST?